# Windows Mobile Custom Textbox

Tags: user-interface, windows-mobile, textbox

I'm trying to replicate the input box shown in the image on windows mobile 5+

[image: Android textbox]

but i'm struggling for ideas!

So far the only things I have come up with (I haven't managed to make either work) were to either;

- inherit TextBox and paint the textbox
  background manually by overriding
  OnPaint/OnPaintBackground
- make the    textbox background
  transparent and    position the
  textbox over an image    that looked
  like the one in the    screen shot

Has anybody done this or know of how this could be acheived?

Thanks in advance

OneShot

Comment: FWIW I did this back with the older compact framework by overriding OnPaintBackground (the older style used to be a horizontal line until it got focus, then it drew the rectangle borders).  Seems like you might need a margin around the input area unless the text box control has a padding property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on this as I have moved away from windows mobile but found that it wasn't possible, due to restrictions in the compact framework, to do this with the existing textbox, you would need to create your own texbox control from scratch!